# Удалить символы при вводе в текстовое поле input

Tags: javascript

Есть текстовое поле input, пользователь должен ввести туда ссылку на свой сайт.

Как с помощь JS сделать, чтобы при вводе в это поле оставалось только название сайта, а всякие https, http, и www удалялись.

То есть человек ввёл https://site.ru и когда страка ввода перестаёт быть в фокусе, лишнее отрезалось и осталось только site.ru.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните, что входит в ваше определение "всякие https, http, и www"? Кроме этого у URL могут быть query параметры. И что именно вы хотите оставить? Только домен? Или путь после домена вам тоже нужен?

Comment: @Inventor: тут _"... страка ввода"_, а Вы про query параметры...

Comment: @Inventor Строка ввода в произвольном порядке. В которую пользователь вписывает адрес сайта. Нужно удалять, то что в начале, а именно https:// или http//:, чтобы оставалось толь доменное имя, то есть site.ru

Comment: <input type="text" name="xfield[website]" id="xf_website" data-alert="Сайт организации" value=""> Так выглядит строка ввода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это одно из возможных решений тебе надо изучить методы строк,регулярные выражения и слушатели событий ну и сами события

```js
const input =  document.querySelector('.my')
input.addEventListener('blur',(e) => {
  input.value = input.value.replace(/.+\/\//g,'')
})
```

```html
    <input class="my" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо, отлично работает.

Comment: @Motor_ka рад помочь

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector('input').oninput = function (evt) {
  evt.target.value = evt.target.value.replace(/http:\/\/|https:\/\/|https:\/\/www\.|www\./gi, '');
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Спасибо, хороший вариант